# Unit test for method with observables and promise

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have this method that I am trying to write a unit test for.
The test currently is just going to spyOn methods being called in the correct order.

```js
      handleSave() {
        this.saving = true;
        this.presenters.presentLoader({
          message: "Uploading..."
        });
        this.loginService.loginToFirebase().subscribe(() => {
          Promise.all(
            this.credential.inputs.map((input) => this.putStorageItem(input))
          )
          .then((url) => {
            this.presenters.dismissLoader();
            this.presenters.presentAlert({
              message: 'Successfully Uploaded Identification.',
              buttons: ['Ok']
            });
            this.presenters.dismissModal(true);
            this.saving = false
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            this.presenters.dismissLoader();
            this.presenters.presentAlert({
              message: 'Something went wrong.'
            });
            this.saving = false
          });
        })
      }
```

The Unit test so far works for the initial call of presentLoader but the subsequent dismissLoader (which is inside the loginToFirebase observable and the Promise.all doesn't get called (at least not before the observable and promises resolve)

In my before each I mock the putStorageItem
`component.putStorageItem = (item) => Promise.resolve(true);`
In and I mock the loginService with this.

```js
    {
      provide: LoginService,
      useValue: {
        loginToFirebase: () => of(true)
      }
    },
```

My current test

```js
    it("call handle save should do stuff", () => {
        let presenters = TestBed.inject(PresentersService);
    
        spyOn(presenters, 'presentLoader');
        spyOn(presenters, 'dismissLoader');
        spyOn(presenters, 'presentAlert');
        spyOn(presenters, 'dismissModal');
    
        component.handleSave();
    
        expect(presenters.presentLoader).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(presenters.dismissLoader).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(presenters.presentAlert).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(presenters.dismissModal).toHaveBeenCalled();
    
      });
```

putStorageItem

```
      putStorageItem(input) {
        const fileExt = input.file.metadata.name.split('.').slice(-1);
        const filepath = ${input.label}.${fileExt}`;
        let task;
        if(input.file.metadata.isBase64) {
          task = this.fireStorage.ref(filepath).put(this.util.b64toBlob(input.file.img), {contentType:input.file.metadata.type, customMetadata:{originalName:input.file.metadata.name}});
        } else {
          task = this.fireStorage.ref(filepath).put(input.file.img, {contentType:input.file.metadata.type, customMetadata:{originalName:input.file.metadata.name}});
        }
        input.fileProgress = task.percentageChanges();
        return task.then((snapshot) => {
          console.log('One success:', input.file)
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.log('One failed:', input.file, error.message)
        });
      }
```

Comment: could you share how `this.putStorageItem` looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using `Observables` and/or `promises`, you need to use different techniques for testing. The techniques are:

- the `done` callback of Jasmine
- `async/await` and `fixture.whenStable()` of Angular
- `waitForAsync` and `fixture.whenStable()` of Angular
- `fakeAsync` and `tick` of Angular

You can read more about asynchronous testing in Angular as well.

My favorite is `fakeAsync` and `tick` and I think it can help you in this scenario.

```
// !! wrap the test in a `fakeAsync` so you have better control of promises
it("call handle save should do stuff", fakeAsync(() => {
        let presenters = TestBed.inject(PresentersService);
    
        spyOn(presenters, 'presentLoader');
        spyOn(presenters, 'dismissLoader');
        spyOn(presenters, 'presentAlert');
        spyOn(presenters, 'dismissModal');
    
        component.handleSave();
        // !! Call tick() to tell the test that before running the
        // statements below the tick, 
        // ensure the promises in the component code have resolved
        // since the expect statements rely on them.
        tick();
    
        expect(presenters.presentLoader).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(presenters.dismissLoader).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(presenters.presentAlert).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(presenters.dismissModal).toHaveBeenCalled();
    
      }));
```

The `tick` can also be used to ensure the `subscribe` of an observable stream has completed before continuing but I mainly use it for promises.